# Do MonoTouch and MonoDroid produce the same ARM6/7 code for both platforms?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, xamarin.android, aot

Do MonoTouch and MonoDroid use the same C#-to-native compiler and GC and thus provide identical performance? Is it the same compiler Mono uses to produce [AOT-compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler) assemblies on Windows?

If I write a completely platform-independent feature, say a JPEG decoder, will it produce the same ARM6/7 code for both platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Depending on your options the generated code could be *similar* but it will never be identical.

MonoTouch on the iOS simulator uses the Mono JIT (x86).

MonoTouch on iOS devices using an AOT compiler, by default it's the one from Mono. Optionally you can use the LLVM-backed AOT compiler. That will be ARMv6, ARMv7 and/or (soon) ARMv7s.

MonoTouch default GC is Boehm. Optionally you can use **sgen** and, as a further option, you can use the *newrefcount** option.

Mono for Android uses the JIT, both on the emulator and on devices (not all devices are ARM-based, even if most are). It also uses the **sgen** garbage collector by default (in fact it cannot use the Boehm collector since it needs to coexists with the Java GC).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, it uses JIT on Android because Android can run x86 as well as ARM and we don't know target platform at compilation?

Comment: One more question: can we use LLVM-backed AOT compiler for MonoMac and on Windows?

Comment: It's more we use **full**-AOT because Apple does not allow the JIT on iOS devices. Also full-AOT is a bit more restrictive than *regular* AOT (like Mono or Microsoft `ngen` provides) since **absolutely** no JITting can occur on the devices.